# Can I use two adverbs in a row?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adverbs

I am completely aware that you can use two adverbs in the same sentence as long as the pronunciation doesn't sound weird. (When two adverbs end with the "ly" sound it often sounds wrong.)

My question is, I wrote a sentence that sounded a bit off to me. So I need help in whether I can keep it like that and if not, what do you suggest I should replace it with? The sentence is "Our smiles are often merely shells to hide our sorrow within."

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Sajida. The way you present your question indicates that you are not a 'learner'. However, you don't add any research results. Looking up "often merely" on (a) a raw Google search and (b) Google Ngrams would probably give some indication of the idiomaticity (how often people use it) of the string, and give you some examples of its use. True, this doesn't give you a definitive answer, but I'll add that _I've_ not found the results of these searches to be surprising. (Still not definitive!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with this sentence. If the -ly after 'often' sounds wrong to you, you could change it to:

> Our smiles are often just shells to hide our sorrow within.

Comment: That was indeed very helpful. I'm not a native speaker and I have never seen the adjective for "merely" so I just assumed that it didn't exist which is kind of stupid now that I think of it haha. Thank you for your help x

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you rephrase it as "Our smiles are often mere shells to hide our sorrow within." 
Here the word mere becomes an adjective to the noun "shells" and has a better ring to it when spoken along in the sentence.

Comment: It depends on the mood you wish to foster. The 'mere' variant is more abrupt, forceful; the 'merely' more introspective, melancholic. / The 'just' variant is the least marked, the most matter-of-fact. I'm not sure it fits the context too well (though it's perfectly grammatical and semantically sound).

Comment: Yes I agree with your point, but isn't that the kind of mood Sajida wants in the sentence ? Using "merely" in the sentence adds a melancholic touch to the sentence like you correctly pointed out. Using "just" fails that purpose.

Comment: Hello, Swasti. This is the exact mood I was going for, thank you. I'm not a native speaker and I didn't know there was an adjective for "merely" haha. Thank you again, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks Sajida. Glad that I could help ! :)
Could you mark it as an accepted answer ?

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm using the website in my phone and I can't find it anywhere. I'll try again when I'm on my computer.